# 碁盤を css で描写することはできる?

Tags: css

ふと、 html 5 で単純なゲームを作ってみたくなりました。その際、盤面の描写はなるべく css でやってみようと思っています。

以下の画像は、[Wikipedia の囲碁のページ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%B2%E7%A2%81)から取得してきたものです。

碁盤の例:
[image: 碁盤]

今、この画像を css でどうにか描写できないかな、と考えています。イメージ、それぞれの石の置くところを div で block として表現して、それぞれのブロックを、以下の様な分割した画像で描写していけば、ひとまず実現できそうだ、と思ってはいるのですが、ここでふと、このようなブロックの中に線があるようなブロックは、css で描写できるものなのだろうか、と疑問に思いました。

[image: goban-plus] [image: goban-t]

## 質問

- 拡大・縮小しても表示が荒れない
- ブロックの中にシンプルなオブジェクト(今回は直線を表す四角形)を何個か表示

を実現したいときに、 css でこれを実現する方法はありますか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. まず、線を描くために [`linear-gradient` 関数](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient())を用いて、黒色 (線の色) のみで構成されるグラデーションを作成します。基本的にはわかりやすさのため、線 1 本に 1 つの `linear-gradient` 関数を使います。

   ```css
   body {
     display: flex;
     gap: 10px;
   }

   div {
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
   }

   .grid1 {
     background-image: 
       linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000),
       linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000);
   }

   .grid2 {
     background-image: 
       linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000),
       linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000);
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="grid1"></div>
   <div class="grid2"></div>
   ```
2. 手順 1 の状態では要素の背景全体が黒色で塗りつぶされてしまうため、 [`background-size` プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)で描画する線の太さおよび長さを指定します。 `background-size` プロパティは複数の値をカンマ区切りで指定することが出来ます。`background-size` プロパティと [`background-image` プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)に指定された値は、指定された順番で対応付いています。

   ```css
   body {
     display: flex;
     gap: 10px;
   }

   div {
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
   }

   .grid1 {
     background-image:
       linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000),
       linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000);
     background-size: 3px 100%, 100% 3px;
   }

   .grid2 {
     background-image:
       linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000),
       linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000);
     background-size: 3px 50%, 100% 3px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="grid1"></div>
   <div class="grid2"></div>
   ```
3. コードスニペットを実行するとわかる通り、手順 2 を実施した後も要素全体は黒色になります。これは背景画像をどのように敷き詰めるかを指定する [`background-repeat` プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)の初期値が `repeat` であり、要素にスペースがある限りそのスペースが黒色の線で埋められてしまうからです。そこで `background-repeat` プロパティに `no-repeat` を指定し、背景画像の繰り返しを行わないようにします。

   ```css
   body {
     display: flex;
     gap: 10px;
   }

   div {
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }

   .grid1 {
     background-image:
       linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000),
       linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000);
     background-size: 3px 100%, 100% 3px;
   }

   .grid2 {
     background-image:
       linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000),
       linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000);
     background-size: 3px 50%, 100% 3px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="grid1"></div>
   <div class="grid2"></div>
   ```
4. 最後に [`background-position` プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)を用いて、それぞれの線の位置を調整します。

   ```css
   body {
     display: flex;
     gap: 10px;
   }

   div {
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }

   .grid1 {
     background-image:
       linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000),
       linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000);
     background-size: 3px 100%, 100% 3px;
     background-position: center center;
   }

   .grid2 {
     background-image:
       linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000),
       linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000);
     background-size: 3px 50%, 100% 3px;
     background-position: center bottom, center center;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="grid1"></div>
   <div class="grid2"></div>
   ```
5. あとは背景色などの装飾を加えれば完成です。完成版のコードは次のようになっています：

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #dcb462;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.grid1 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000),
    linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000);
  background-size: 3px 100%, 100% 3px;
  background-position: center center;
}

.grid2 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000),
    linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000);
  background-size: 3px 50%, 100% 3px;
  background-position: center bottom, center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid1"></div>
<div class="grid2"></div>
```

Comment: グラデーションは UA によって描画されるため、質問文中の「拡大・縮小しても表示が荒れない」についても解決出来ていると思います。